# loading multiple xml files in to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have list of xml files. (reading from one directory) 
I want to show all the records present in each xml files in datagrid.

here is code for the same ( xaml file)

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[TestResult]}"  x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,0,-1,0">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="TestCaseId" Binding="{Binding Path=Attribute[TestCaseId].Value}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Outcome" Binding="{Binding Path=Attribute[Outcome].Value}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Binding="{Binding Path=Attribute[Duration].Value}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding Path= Attribute[Comment].Value}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

TestREsult Class

```
class TestResult
{      
        [XmlAttribute("TestCaseId")]
        public string TestCaseId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Outcome")]
        public string Outcome { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Duration")]
        public string Duration { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Comment")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
Here is the code for loading each file in to datagrid
```

however I can able to see only last file data

```
  foreach (string item in Files)
        {

           var peopleList = XElement.Load(item);
           this.dataGrid.DataContext = peopleList;

        }
```

Here is the one xml file

```
 <TestResults URL="https://google.com/" StartDateTime="2016-11-11T14:52:25.2499848+05:30">
<TestResult TestCaseId="Smoke_21949" Outcome="Pass" Duration="00:03:09.9335101" Comment="" />
<TestResult TestCaseId="Smoke_31234" Outcome="Pass" Duration="00:02:56.1503179" Comment="" />
</TestResults>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list and add to the list,

```
var peopleList = new List<XElement>();
foreach (string item in Files)
    {
       peopleList.Add(XElement.Load(item));           
    }
this.dataGrid.DataContext = peopleList;
```

Comment: any change in xaml ? at this line ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[TestResult]}"

Comment: you cant directly set this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = peopleList; remove from xaml

Comment: I solved it but now I am merging all xml files in to single file and then setting one xml file  for datacontext , its working